# How to find maximum value of a column in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark`. In this data frame I have column called `id` that is unique.

Now I want to find the `maximum` value of the column `id` in the data frame.

I have tried like below

```
df['id'].max()
```

But got below error

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Please let me know how to find the `maximum` value of a column in data frame

> In the answer by @Dadep the link gives the correct answer

Comment: How do you create your data frame ? do you use `pandas` ?

Comment: This looks like a `spark` dataframe to me. Perhaps, you need to add a `spark` or `pyspark` tag or both to your question.

Comment: Please try to share a [mcve]. The best I can say is: it should work if all what you said is true.

Comment: @Abdou yes it is a spark dataframe

Comment: @Dadep No I don't use `pandas`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if you are using pandas `.max()` will work :

```
>>> df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,5,0], 'B':[3, 5, 6]})
>>> df2['A'].max()
5
```

Else if it's a `spark` dataframe:

[Best way to get the max value in a Spark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224740/best-way-to-get-the-max-value-in-a-spark-dataframe-column)

Comment: I had to run with df2.A.max() to make it work ... if its a help to anyone else

Answer (score 2):

I'm coming from scala, but I do believe that this is also applicable on python.

```
val max = df.select(max("id")).first()
```

but you have first import the following :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
```

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used in pyspark:

```
df.select(max("id")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregate max as also mentioned in the pyspark documentation link below:

Link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg

Code:

```
row1 = df1.agg({"id": "max"}).collect()[0]
```