# how to extract highest price using datareader python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract the highest price but I dont know how here is my code:

```
import pandas
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2021,1,29)
end = dt.datetime(2021,2,18)
df = pdr.DataReader('BTC-USD','yahoo',start,end)
```

it returns cloumns and i want to print just the highest price

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find maximum value of a column and return the corresponding row values using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan)

Comment: [How to find maximum value of a column in python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43924686/15497888)

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in the maximal values of the `High` column, you can calculate it like:

```
df['High'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `idxmax`

```
maxrow = df.loc[df['col'].idxmax()]
```