# Get the column index where the value is maximum per each row in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe such as:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | ... | ColN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 5 | 21 | ... | -9 |
| 2 | 87 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 95 | 1 | ... | 1 |

How one could create a pyspark dataframe column `MAX` that represents the index column where the value is maximum per row such as:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | ... | ColN | MAX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 5 | 21 | ... | -9 | 3 |
| 2 | 87 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 95 | 1 | ... | 1 | 2 |

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224740/best-way-to-get-the-max-value-in-a-spark-dataframe-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a column with the max in each row

List columns in which the max value can be found

Eliminate the NaNs in the list

Code below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import*
w=Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy().rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)
df=(df.withColumn(
    "max",
    F.greatest(*[F.col(x) for x in df.columns[1:]])#Find the max in each row
)
.withColumn(
  'maxcol', array(*[when(col(c) ==col('max'), lit(c)) for c in df.columns])#Find intersection of max with all other columns
).withColumn(
  'maxcol', expr("filter(maxcol, x -> x is not null)")#Filter ou the nans in the intersection
).show())

+---+----+----+----+----+---+------+
| ID|Col1|Col2|Col3|ColN|max|maxcol|
+---+----+----+----+----+---+------+
|  1|  10|   5|  21|  -9| 21|[Col3]|
|  2|  87|   1|   1|   1| 87|[Col1]|
|  3|   1|  95|   1|   1| 95|[Col2]|
+---+----+----+----+----+---+------+
```

You could also use pandas_udf though I am not sure of the efficacy
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def max_col(a:pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  s=a.isin(a.iloc[:,1:].max(1))
  return a.assign(maxcol=s.agg(lambda x: x.index[x].values, axis=1))
schema=StructType([\
                  StructField('ID',LongType(),True),\
                  StructField('Col1',LongType(),True),\
                  StructField('Col2',LongType(),True),\
                  StructField('Col3',LongType(),True),\
                  StructField('ColN',LongType(),True),\
                  StructField('maxcol',ArrayType(StringType(),True),False)\
                 ])
df.groupby('ID').applyInPandas(max_col, schema).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.show(5)
```

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 | 5 | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 7 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 | 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 2 |

only showing top 5 rows

```
df = df.withColumn("data", F.array(df.columns)) 
max_index = F.udf(lambda x: x.index(max(x)))  
df = df.withColumn("max_index", max_index("data")) 
df = df.drop("data")
df.show(5)
```

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | max_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 7 | 5 | 8 | 8 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 7 | 7 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

only showing top 5 rows