# How to query for the maximum / highest value in an field with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

The following dataframe will produce values 0 to 3.

```
df = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1').history().select(col("version"))
```

[image]

Can someone show me how to modify the dataframe such that it only provides the maximum value i.e 3?

I have tried

```
df.select("*").max("version")
```

And

```
df.max("version")
```

But no luck

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `df.select(max("version").alias("version")).show()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to get the max value in a Spark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224740/best-way-to-get-the-max-value-in-a-spark-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.max.html) function, This should work:

```
df.select(F.max("version").alias("max_version")).show()
```

or

```
df.agg(F.max("version").alias("max_version")).show()
```

Input:

```
+-------+
|version|
+-------+
|      0|
|      1|
|      3|
|      2|
+-------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
|max_version|
+-----------+
|          3|
+-----------+
```